# Laravel Fetch entries without n latest entries

Tags: php, laravel

In my Laravel Project, I want to return all entries which are not the nth latest entry in the database.

for example : I want to fetch all entries **without** fetching the latest `n` (2) entry.

```
|id| name | updated_at          |
|--|------|---------------------|
|1 |a     | 2017-09-21 06:27:59 |
|2 |b     | 2017-09-19 06:20:29 |
|3 |c     | 2017-09-12 05:27:59 |
|4 |d     | 2017-09-18 05:17:39 |
|5 |e     | 2017-09-17 06:27:48 |
|6 |b     | 2017-09-19 06:27:59 |
|7 |f     | 2017-09-04 06:27:58 |
|8 |g     | 2017-09-06 06:27:14 |
```

expected Output

```
|1 |a     | 2017-09-21 06:27:59 |
|2 |b     | 2017-09-19 06:20:29 |
|3 |c     | 2017-09-12 05:27:59 |
|4 |d     | 2017-09-18 05:17:39 |
|5 |e     | 2017-09-17 06:27:48 |
|6 |b     | 2017-09-19 06:27:59
```

Comment: something like `ORDER BY updated_at DESC OFFSET 2`

Comment: $values = DB::table('users')->skip(2)->orderByDesc('id')->take(DB::table('users')->count()-2)->get(); not an good way i guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can sort by updated_at column descending then skip the first two results:

```
      $values = DB::table('token_users')->orderByDesc('updated_at')->skip(2)->take(DB::table('token_users')->count()-2)->get();
```

Comment: ` Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'offset 2' at line 1 (SQL: select `token` from `token_users` where `user_id` = 89 order by `id` desc offset 2)`

Comment: you can supply take method to confirm your query, see the update

Comment: Thank you It  really helped

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this with Eloquent, you can use the `take` in conjunction with `count` to grab all but the last 2 records.

```php
Model::take(Model::count() - 2);
```

I don't know the name of your Eloquent `Model`, so replace `Model` with whatever you've called your `Model`.